# Modify Extension Method To Allow ThenBy

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I have the following custom extension method, which allows you to dynamically specify which field will be sorted - it is used to tie into a JQuery DataTable.

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderByField<T>(this IQueryable<T> q, string SortField, string SortDirection)
{

  var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
  var prop = Expression.Property(param, SortField);
  var exp = Expression.Lambda(prop, param);

  var method = SortDirection == "asc" ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending";

  var types = new Type[] { q.ElementType, exp.Body.Type };
  var mce = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), method, types, q.Expression, exp);

  return q.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(mce);

}
```

It is then called as follows: `.OrderByField("ColumnName", "asc")` where the two params are strings.

I wish to modify this function to allow "thenby" to be called immediately after, however I am unsure how to do this.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should use an enum for `SortDirection`.

Comment: The values are populated directly from an AJAX request. Can MVC bind to an enum?

Comment: Make sure to also look at the more recent answers of the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `OrderBy()` or `OrderByDescending()` directly (not through `CreateQuery()`), then return the `IOrderedQueryable<T>`.

Comment: how would you go about doing this though, OrderBy doesn't have an override that allows you to pass the field name as a string.

Comment: @GavinCoates: You need to pass it an `Expression<Func<T, TValue>>`.  You may need Reflection to invoke it generically.

Comment: Can you demonstrate how to do that?